# Flask-RESTful can we call a method before get and post in Ressource?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm using Flask-RESTful in my app.

I would want to call a method before each Ressource post and get so my code is not duplicated.

So basically here is what I have:

```
class SomeClass(Resource):
    def __init__():
        # Some stuff

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        # some code

    def post(self, **kwargs):
        # the same code as in get method
```

I would like to have a method call before get and post so my code is not duplicated.

Is there any way I can achieve to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try writing a decorator function and use it with your `get()` and `post()` methods. More info [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html).

A decorator is more like a wrapper to your function, where your function is wrapped in a function that returns your function.

Say, you want to do some validation before processing, you can write a decorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def validate(actual_method):
    @wraps(actual_method)  # preserves signature
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do your validation here

        return actual_method(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

then, using it in your code is as simple as:

```
class SomeClass(Resource):
    def __init__():
        # Some stuff

    @validate
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        # some code

    @validate
    def post(self, **kwargs):
        # the same code as in get method
```